# How to add multiple items to a list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an app where users can add items to a list and I decided, for the sake of learning, to use Angular (which I'm very new to). So far, I've been able to successfully add a single item to that list without any issues. Unfortunately, whenever I try to add more than one without a page refresh, I get an error - specifically a "Undefined is not a function."

I've spent more time than I care to think about trying to resolve this issue and I'm hoping an expert out there can give me a hand. Here's what I have so far:

***Controllers:***

```
angular.module('streakApp')
    .controller('StreakController', function($scope) {

        // Removed REST code since it isn't relevant

        $scope.streaks = Streak.query();

        // Get user info and use it for making new streaks

        var userInfo = User.query(function() {
            var user = userInfo[0];
            var userName = user.username;
            $scope.newStreak = new Streak({
                'user': userName
            });
        });


    })
    .controller('FormController', function($scope) {
        // Works for single items, not for multiple items
        $scope.addStreak = function(activity) {
            $scope.streaks.push(activity);
            $scope.newStreak = {};

        };

    });
```

***View:***

```
 <div class="streaks" ng-controller="FormController as formCtrl">
  <form name="streakForm" novalidate >
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Add an activity</legend>
        <input ng-model="newStreak.activity" placeholder="Activity" required />
        <input ng-model="newStreak.start" placeholder="Start" type="date" required />
        <input ng-model="newStreak.current_streak" placeholder="Current streak" type="number" min="0" required />
        <input ng-model="newStreak.notes" placeholder="Notes" />
        <button type="submit" ng-click="addStreak(newStreak)">Add</button>
      </fieldset>
  </form>

  <h4>Current streaks: {{ streaks.length }}</h4>

  <div ng-show="newStreak.activity">
  <hr>
  <h3>{{ newStreak.activity }}</h3>
  <h4>Current streak: {{ newStreak.current_streak }}</h4>
  <p>Start: {{ newStreak.start | date }}</p>
  <p>Notes: {{ newStreak.notes }}</p>
  <hr>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="user_streak in streaks">
  <!-- Removed most of this for simplicity -->
  <h3>{{ user_streak.fields }}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the html of StreakController too? Your solution works fine in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zf9y0yyg/1/

```
.controller('FormController', function($scope) {
    $scope.streaks = [];
    // Works for single items, not for multiple items
    $scope.addStreak = function(activity) {
        $scope.streaks.push(activity);
        $scope.newStreak = {};

    };

});
```

The $scope inject in each controller is different, so you have to define the "streaks" in FormController.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems comes from :

```
.controller('FormController', function($scope) {
        // Works for single items, not for multiple items
        $scope.addStreak = function(activity) {
            $scope.streaks.push(activity); 
                    ^^^^^^
                    // Streaks is initialized in another controller (StreakController) 
                    // therefore, depending of when is instantiated StreakController,
                    // you can have an error or not

            $scope.newStreak = {};

        };
});
```

A better design would be to **implement a StreakService**, and to **inject that service** in the controller you need it. Of course, initializing `$scope.streaks` in FormController will make your code work, but that's not the responsibility of ***Form***Controller to initialize this data.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `FormController` is a nested controller of `StreakController`, so they share the same scope.
if that works for single object, it should work for mulitiple objects, the problems is you can't just use `push` to push an array of object to the streaks, you can `for loop` the array and add them individually or use push.apply trick. I thought the reason of `Undefined is not a function.` is because the Stack.query() return an element instead of an array of elements so, the method push doesn't exists on the `$scope.streaks`.

http://jsbin.com/jezomutizo/2/edit